# what does the '->' token mean in Rust?

Tags: rust, syntax

I'm digging into Rust for the first time, with a primarily ObjC and Javascript (sigh) background, and working with a few of the playgrounds.

I'm trying to understand the `->` (aka "thin arrow??") symbol in Rust and how I am supposed to interpret this when reading Rust statements

Comment: I really suggest you look through the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-03-how-functions-work.html#functions-with-return-values)

Comment: doesnt mean much but I started sifting through it before I asked this question! While I appreciate you sharing the direct link, separately, it would be nice if more of this documentation was indexed on these kinds of questions to help n00bs jump in with specific questions faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rust `->` specifies the return type of the function. In Rust, functions need to specify their return type (if it isn't `()`, the empty return type).

So when you declare a function that adds one to an `i32`, you have to specify the return type `i32` of the function like this:

```rust
fn add_one(x: i32) -> i32 
{
   x+1
}
```

You have to declare `x+1` to add one and return the value. Note that when you return the value you do not use a semicolon after `x+1;`. A semicolon means it is a statement and not a return expression. In Rust, expressions without semicolons are return value expressions.